# Installing a wildcard SSL certificate in Red Hat 6 hosted on Azure

Tags: apache, azure, ssl, redhat

Short version: I have a wildcard certificate for a domain.  We presently have 2 Apache servers, using Red Hat 6.8, running on the Azure cloud.

My question is: How do I install the wildcard certificate, and have it work properly, since the URL is (for example) http://mysite-prod01.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com -- but the certificate is for *.mydomain.com?

We're using Traffic Manager for www.mydomain.com, as the 'front' for the 2 web servers.  Any ideas?  I've searched and found installing SSL certificates on Red Hat, which isn't an issue, or installing certificates on Windows Azure.

There have to be a fair number of folks hosting their Red Hat servers on Azure, so this must have been solved before ... thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with Azure. Install the certs as you would normally do and CNAME your domain to the traffic manager endpoint.

```
www.example.com   IN  CNAME   something.trafficmanager.net
```

[image: Traffic Manager]

Traffic Manager works at the DNS level, so you don't handshake TLS with it, you do it with one of the VMs, depending which endpoint you get.